# Canot connect to postgresql server from out

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to connect to postgresql from another server but occur below error. i search and find some result like below but after do these again error occured

in **postgresql.conf** change **listen_addresses** from **localhost** to *

in **pg_hba.conf** change **127.0.0.1/32**  to **0.0.0.0/0**

reboot server

Error:

> could not connect to server: Connection refused.Is the server running
>   on host "Ip Number" 
>       and accepting.TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Comment: If connecting from localhost works, the cause of your problem probably lies within the firewall of the server Postgres is running on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you should do as the following steps.

1. Check your PostgreSQL SERVER is running.
2. Check the listen_addresses parameter ( postgresql.conf )
3. Check the port number of your postgresql ( The port parameter of 
   postgresql.conf )
4. Check your the firewall policy  of your  database server , set
   that allow the port of your postgresql.
5. If you want to connect your db from another server,  may be you
   shoud set the pg_hba.conf as following :

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD
    local   all             all                                     trust
    host   all     all     0.0.0.0/0       md5
```

Comment: I check all of your steps,but again can't access

Comment: @SajjadZare Then maybe a firewall/router *between* your DB server and the outside is filtering the traffic out. Use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` to trace. Also make sure you aren't using a private IP like 196.168.x.x, 172... or 10.x.x.x and that you don't have any NAT in place.

Comment: Is it possible to use tcpdump  in ssh?

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if the network traffic reaches the server. You can sniff the network traffic to see what happen. Meassure on client and server and check the communication.

```
sudo tcpdump -A -n -s 0 -w test_on_client.log port 5432
```

After you try your connect stop tcpdump with CTRL-C and inspect the log file with Wireshark.
This procedure will find every network connection problems.